# Google maps API on android not reseting state

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am working on an android app which is using Google maps API, where I have a Fragment that contains **SupportMapFragment** inside it (composition).

When this Fragment gets shown and if a different level is selected (say, 3), and if I navigate away from that Activity that contains this Fragment (I am finishing the activity) and then navigate back to the same Activity that contains this Fragment, it retains the level (i.e. 3).

I have this specific requirement where I wanna clear it's complete state every time user revisits the Maps.

I have *'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'* as dependency in gradle. I have tried keeping **MapView** instead of **MapFragment**, also tried with **useViewLifecycleInFragment** flag set to true. Somehow its caching the state and I can not find how to clear it.

The API level with which I am trying this is 21 (Lollipop)

Comment: try setting `addToBackStack(null)` for the fragmentTransaction

Comment: doesn't work, I don't think its in any way related to fragment navigation, I am not even storing any state in the fragment myself, its google MapFragment itself that is internally storing its state (maybe some GLSurfaceView cache or something), earlier I had thought that there is some Singleton thats being used by MapFragment with Application Context so that the state remains, but I couldn't figure out any such thing. Still the problem remains